# How to represent an int as a string in an Array

Tags: java

I am attempting to represent an `int` as a `String` using the `toString()` method and I am not exactly sure how to achieve the desired results.

what I have is:

```
public class Item {
  int item;
  public Item () {
    item = 3;
  }

  public Item (int item) { 
    this.item = item;     
  }

  public void toString() {
    String[] anArray = new string[10];

    anArray[0] = "item 0";
    anArray[1] = "item1";
    anArray[2] = "item2";
    anArray[3] = "item3";
    anArray[4] = "item4";
    anArray[5] = "item5";
    anArray[6] = "item6";
    anArray[7] = "item7";
    anArray[8] = "item8";
    anArray[9] = "item9";

    if (item >= 0 && item < 10)
      System.out.println("Item " + item + " = " + anArray[item]);
    else 
      System.out.println("Item does not exist.");
  }
}
```

How can I represent an `int` as a `String` in an array?

Comment: First of all, int is not a class. It's a primitive type.

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: I cannot figure what exactly do you want to achieve, I see no problems in your code.

Comment: int is not a class..its primitive type and second thing is that your question is not clear

Comment: String.valueOf(yourInt) converts your int to string.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. It's not printing when I compile. The code is going to be used as gamification software, so as Items are created  a gamer will be able to collect the items:            public class Gamer {

  Item my_item;
public Gamer(int item)
{
my_item = new Item(item);
}

Comment: I hope that was more clear..im a ultra noob as you can see

Comment: java doesn't execute any of your code during compilation. The printing would only happen if you ever called `toString()` but the code probably doesn't compile since `toString()` must return `String`, not `void`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
 public String toString() {
     return "Item " + item;
 }
```

The idea of the `toString()` method is that it returns a simple but meaningful representation of the instance.

Usually, you should include the name of the class (you can use `getClass().getSimpleName()` or a string) plus a few key fields.

Comment: I don't understand how this is implemented. do I place arguments within this method? I'm just confused as to how it would actually work with the code that I have. ps..I'm a noob

Comment: Read up on "fields" and "arguments" and what an "instance" is.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear exactly what is your desired result, but if you want to have a `toString` method that returns "item1" when `item` is 1, "item2" when `item` is 2, and so forth, you should bear in mind:

- `toString()` should return a `String`.
- You don't need to construct an array, but just to return the concatenation of "item" and the value of `item`.

This would be:

```
public String toString() {
    return "item" + item;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you

```
String str = Integer.toString(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

**int to String:**

```
int a=9;
String b = Integer.toString(a);
```

and

**String to int:**

```
String a="9";
int b=Integer.parseInt(a);
```

Comment: `a` is a primitive. Doesn't have any methods.